# Genfromtxt file name

Tags: python, file, numpy, names, genfromtxt

I am trying to read a file name stored as a string in a data file.  No problem there.  If I pass it to genfromtxt I get error "IOError: Z:\Python\Rb input.txt not found."  if I put the file name into genfromtxt explicitly it works

this fails with error "IOError: Z:\Python\Rb input.txt not found."

```
import numpy
modat = open('z:\python\mot1 input.txt') # open file with names in
rbfile = modat.readline()                # read data file name
print rbfile                             # print the file name
rb = numpy.genfromtxt(rbfile, delimiter =',')
print rb
```

but his works

```
import numpy
modat = open('z:\python\mot1 input.txt') # open file with names in
rbfile = modat.readline()                # read data file name
print rbfile
rb = numpy.genfromtxt('z:\python\Rb input.txt', delimiter =',')
print rb
```

the 2 print statements give

```
%run "c:\users\ian\appdata\local\temp\tmpkiz1n0.py"
Z:\Python\Rb input.txt

[[  2.  10.]
 [  3.  11.]
 [  5.  13.]
 [ 10.  15.]
 [ 15.  16.]
 [ 20.  16.]
 [ 30.  22.]]
```

It appears to be to do with now the string is passed - any suggestions please

Comment: Did you try it with `rbfile.rstrip()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rbfile` has an End-Of-Line (EOL) character (e.g. `\r\n`) at the end. Strip it off:

```
rb = numpy.genfromtxt(rbfile.strip(), delimiter =',')
```

---

By the way, to debug problems with strings, it is often more useful to print the `repr` of the string than the string itself:

```
print(repr(rbfile))
```

because the repr will show characters such as `'\r\n'` more clearly.

---

[`file.readline()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) does not strip EOF characters:

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character
>   (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last
>   line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the
>   return value unambiguous;

Comment: Magic !  I have messed around for ages with that, thanks for the help